# How to get number of rows per group by partition in mysql?

Tags: mysql, group-by

In mysql, if you have a table like this

```
A | B
------
1 | 0
1 | 0
1 | 0
2 | 0
2 | 0
3 | 0
3 | 0
3 | 0
3 | 0
```

How can you turn it into

```
A | c
------
1 | 3
2 | 2
3 | 4
```

c is the count column, so there was 3 1's, 2 2's and 4 3's.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Comment: In MySQL (or indeed any RDBMS), if you have a table like this, then you don't really have a table! A PRIMARY KEY is a prerequisite of a relational table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
     select count(A) from table group by A;
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it like this:

```
SELECT A, count(*) as c FROM table GROUP BY A;
```

check this SQLFiddle to play around with it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/36c59/1

Comment: You should never count(*) it's unnecessarily wasteful. Always count(1) you get the same result and it's more efficient.